# Como verificar se é Internet Explorer menor que versão 10?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, navegador-de-internet

Preciso fazer uma verificação do browser para saber se é Internet Explorer e se é  menor do que a versão 10.

Como fazer?

**PS:** Minha idéia é dizer pro usuário se estiver usando uma versão inferior ao 10 que baixe um navegador mais atual.

Comment: Geralmente isso não é uma boa ideia, é melhor verificar se uma funcionalidade específica está disponível do que checar qual é o browser. Claro que sempre existem exceções, mas não sei qual seria o caso aqui.

Comment: Se realmente quer chegar verifique se na string user agent o ultimo numero e' menor que 6.0 `Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/6.0)`

Answer (score 3):

O Internet Explorer tem uma propriedade do `document` que dá isso. É o `documentMode`.

Teste este código:

```
alert(document.documentMode); // dá o numero da versão do IE
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t5Lup/

Porem, e como o [bfavaretto referiu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21048/como-verificar-se-%C3%A9-internet-explorer-menor-que-vers%C3%A3o-10/21050#comment38141_21048) o melhor é confiar no "feature detection", detectar funcionalidades, pois isso é mais fiável.

Um exemplo bom foi quando a versão 11 do IE saiu eles decidiram mudar a UA string e toda a gente teve problemas com isso.

Aqui fica um link interessante com mais alternativas: http://tanalin.com/en/articles/ie-version-js/

---

Se quiser detectar dentro do HTML (sem JavaScript necessáriamente)  pode usar comentários de código que só o IE detecta. Por exemplo:

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]><script>
    ie = 7;
</script><![endif]-->
```

`lte` quer dizer IE<=7, somente `lt` quer dizer IE<7

Answer (score 2):

Uma outra forma é, verificar a existência de alguns objetos e combinar algumas verificações.

A tabela a seguir contém as condições prontas para uso.

```
Versões do IE   Verificar condição
10+             document.all 
9+              document.all &&! ​​Window.atob 
8+              document.all &&! ​​Document.addEventListener 
7+              document.all &&! ​​Document.querySelector 
6+              document.all &&! ​​Window.XMLHttpRequest 
5.x             document.all &&! ​​Document.compatMode
```

No exemplo a seguir a condição é verdadeira se o navegador é *IE11+* ou não.

```
if (!document.all) {
    alert('Voce utiliza o IE11+ ou um outro navegador');
}
```

<sub>[**Fonte**](http://tanalin.com/en/articles/ie-version-js/)</sub>

Comment: Isso dá certo com o IE de aparelhos móveis/Windows RT também?